# Automatically retrieving all the sub-concepts associated to a given concept

Tags: computational-linguistics

I wonder if you know how automatically obtain all the sub-concepts associated to a given concept. For example, given the concept car, I would like to automatically retrieve concepts such as: wheel, brake, window, seat belt, etc...

Of course, the way to do that could be using a taxonomy. However, this method does not satisfy my needs since: the taxonomies that I know only cover small domains, they are not homogeneously formatted, and it is not always clear that a given taxon is a real subsumption of the parent concept.

I am looking for a more general approach. Things that I have already tried:

- Computing embeddings of the concept. It does not work.
- Mining a corpus in search of hyponymy patterns. It does not work.
- Looking for manually compiled theasurus which can offer this info. I could not find an appropriate one. Most of them offer: synonyms, antonyms, related words, but not real sub-concepts

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Do you want something that works for concepts in a specific language, or something cross-linguistic?

Comment: Just for a specific language.

Comment: Which language?

Comment: Well, preferably in English, or at least in a language which can be easily translated into English

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need is to look for Knowledge Bases (KBs). Among the most popular ones are [DBPedia](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/) and [YAGO](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/yago/#c10444), which are free to use. Each concept of the KB is related with other concepts in the KB. For instance, on the YAGO web-site, there is this example:

[image]

As you can see in the image, there are many concepts. The main concept investigated is Max Planck, which is a physicist, a physicist is a scientist, which is a person. Also, you have relation between the concept "Max Planck" and the concept "Nobel Prize", and the relation is *hasWon*, meaning that Max Planck has won a Nobel Prize. You can see there are many other concepts, like locations, temporal concepts, etc.

In order to get a better feeling of how these things work, I would suggest you play around with the [OpenLink faceted browser with DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/fct/). If you look for a concept, for instance - [car](http://dbpedia.org/fct/facet.vsp?cmd=text&sid=2080), you can get all kinds of information about the concept and how it relates with other concepts.